# How to create a view that calls stored functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created 2 tables.  One contains 5 golf courses (name & address). the other is the par and yards for all 18 holes per golf course (foreign key to link to courses).  I have created a function getYards to return the number of yards for a course.  I have created a 2nd function, getPar, to return the total par for a course.  These each work.  I now need to create a view to display the course name and the par and yardage using the 2 functions.
getYards function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION getYards (id INT)

RETURNS INT (5)

BEGIN

    DECLARE totalyards INT;

    SELECT SUM(hole_yards) INTO totalyards FROM golf_holes WHERE id=golf_id;

    RETURN totalyards;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The function for getPar is very similar using hole_par instead of yards.

So now I want to create a view with course name, par and yardage using the getPar and getYards functions.  I have tried searching and I'm just not knowledgeable enough to understand.  I know this is vague, but can anyone help me ... keep it simple!  thanx in advance.

I've been a cobol programmer for almost 40 years. I am trying to learn MySQL so have very little knowledge with SQL.

Comment: Hope it's okay with you, I edited your top line of your post to be a more descriptive question. Stack Overflow likes the title line to be a summary of your actual question. I moved your description of your programming background to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, I would not recommend using stored functions in your view definition.

Instead you can just join the two tables.

Something like this should work for you:

```
create or replace view v_golf_courses as
select golf_courses.id as golf_course_id,
  golf_courses.name as golf_course_name, 
  sum(golf_holes.yards) as course_yardage, 
  sum(golf_holes.par) as course_par
from golf_courses
  inner join golf_holes on golf_holes.golf_course_id = golf_courses.id
group by golf_courses.id, golf_courses.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the id column in your courses table is also named golf_id

```
SELECT name, getPar(golf_id) as par, getYards(golf_id) as yards
FROM courses
```

However you don't really need UDF's for this:

```
SELECT a.name, sum(b.hole_par) as total_par, sum(b.hole_yards) as total_yards
FROM courses a
JOIN golf_holes b
ON a.golf_id = b.golf_id
GROUP BY a.golf_id
```